# WCF service will create other appliaction to handle request of its client

Tags: c#, c

I have developed WCF service.Now the requirement is,suppose client1 call wcf through URL.then WCF service will create one server side EXE1 which will communicate with client1(after this client1 can communicate only with EXE1 not with WCF service).
If client2  call WCF service,then service will create EXE2 which will communicate with client2 & so on for client3 client4

How can i do that.

Please reply

Comment: 1) What are you trying to achieve? 
2) Are you sure that separate process must be started, not another service?

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Why spawn new hosting processes for each separate client call?

Comment: To avoid multithreading..its  my team leader requirement

Comment: Dear dennis is it possible to create multiple instance of gsoapserver service(EXE1..EXE2 etc)...so each instance is for appropriate cleint